# Trying to "loop" a function in R

Tags: r

Might be a silly question, but I currently have a dataset containing info about different species. Now I need to make a new datasets containing only specific info (look at code below), is there a way I can "loop" this instead of copy and pasting this code 20 times and changing the species filter?

```
data_abundance_GL <- TSVPlast %>% 
  filter(species == "GL") %>% # filter to select the species of interest
  group_by(method, observer) %>%
  summarise(abundance = length(species))
```

edit:

Reason for asking is that I need to plot the abundance of every single species against the 3 different methods, including how many were counted from each observer. This I have done using

```
ggplot(data = data_abundance_GL, aes(x = method, y = abundance))+ geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.35, fill = c("orange3", "royalblue", "seagreen3"))+
  geom_jitter(aes(shape = observer), size = 4, width = 0.3, height = 0, col = "black")+ 
  scale_shape_manual(values = 1:length(data_abundance_GL$observer))+ 
  labs(shape = "Observer group", fill = "Method", x = "\nMethod", y = "Relative abundance\n", title = "2.4a")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(), 
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 18),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 16, colour = "black"),
          strip.background = element_blank(),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 16),
         title = element_text(size = 30),
          strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

Comment: Long term it's better not to create a bunch of separate variables with data *in* their names. You could split the data into a list, but dplyr make it so easy to work with groups what likely what you want to accomplish can be done with a `group_map()` or something in one step. In R it's better to avoid automatically creating a bunch of separate variables. Store related in lists so you can easily map functions over them.

Comment: Thanks, will remember this for later. Kinda new to R so not aware of all the different packages and functions yet.

Comment: I think you want `dplyr::count(TSVPlast, species, method, observer)`. This will give all the information in the same dataframe though.

Comment: Pretty close yes. I guess I was not clear enough in my question, as I need to plot the abundance for every single species against each method.

Comment: Can't you remove the `filter` altogether, also group by `species` and `summarise(abundance = n())`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```r
for (specie in unique(TSVPlast$species)) {
  TSVPlast %>% 
    filter(species == specie) %>% # filter to select the species of interest
    group_by(method, observer) %>%
    summarise(abundance = length(species)) %>%
    print()
  
  TSVPlast %>% 
    filter(species == specie) %>% # filter to select the species of interest
    ggplot(aes(x = method, y = abundance)) +
    geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.35, fill = c("orange3", "royalblue", "seagreen3"))

  # ggsave(str_c(specie, ".pdf))
}
```